# What am I doing wrong with using arrays?

Tags: java

I'm trying to fill an array using a method and later print that array out.

However when I try to do so all it gives me are zeroes. I think my fill method is not working properly but I'm not sure why. I'm trying to understand arrays but so far no good. I would prefer an explanation rather than an answer. If I can get this myself it would be best.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class diverScore {
    static double score = 0;
    static double validDegreeOfDiff = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] score = new double[6];
        inputAllScores(score);
        printArray(score);
    }

    public static double[] inputAllScores(double[] x) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        double[] array_score = new double[6];
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            System.out.println("What is the score given by the judge?");
            array_score[i] = s.nextDouble();
        }
       return array_score;
    }

    public static void printArray(double[] j) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            System.out.println("The array is:" + j[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
import java.util.Scanner;



public class DiverScore  {
    static double score = 0;
    static double validDegreeOfDiff = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
//        double[] score = new double[6];
        double[] score = inputAllScores(/*score*/);
        printArray(score);
    }

    public static double[] inputAllScores(/*double[] x*/) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        double[] array_score = new double[6];
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            System.out.println("What is the score given by the judge?");
            array_score[i] = s.nextDouble();
        }
       return array_score;
    }

    public static void printArray(double[] j) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            System.out.println("The array is:" + j[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `inputAllScores`, you're writing to a new local array, and returning it, but you're not using the returned array.  It would be better if you wrote to the array that you passed into that method (which inside the method is called `x`).

Answer (score 0):

```
double[] score = new double[6];
```

This line simply initializes an array of type double with 6 indexes allocated for it, with each resulting in 0 when printed out.

You could simply change the code in main to this, thus actually using the return value of the inputAllScores function.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] score = new double[6];
    printArray(inputAllScores(score));
}
```

HTH